# Are constructs such with a hyphen and slash (e.g. "on-/offline") common?

Tags: hyphenation, slash

Are constructs using a slash combined with a hyphen to switch a prefix such as in "on-/offline" as a short-form of "online/offline" (or rather "on-line/off-line") which again stands for "online or offline" (which could be written as "on- or offline") something a native English <s>speaker</s> reader would understand right away?

Comment: I think it depends on how familiar readers are with the words in which you're thinking of using a [suspended hyphen.](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/suspended-hyphen/hot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be understood. However, this is a style issue. There are style manuals one may follow. I use the *Chicago Manual of Style*.

In formal writing, slashes and parentheses are frowned on; such as *24/7, (s)he, he/she,* *and/or* and *on/offline*.

However, things having slashes or parentheses as a convention are alright: *on/off switch*, fractions, area codes, interpolations, etc.

Sentences with examples similar to yours should be rewritten to retain meaning. An additional problem is non-native speakers could be confused.

Try,

*I am going online and offline as soon as I get home and find out where I'm at.*

*Documents can be printed either online or offline.*

However, in less formal writing, you don't have to be too careful with style as long as your target audience understands your message.

Still, because *online* and *offline* are not hyphenated in modern dictionaries, you wouldn't hyphenate in your construction.

**off/online** or **on/offline** are accepted, but *on-/offline* looks awkward to me. A construction where the words in question would normally be hyphenated would be an exception: *para-/ortho-oxygenated side chains*

Comment: I'm trying to work out whether the less awkward-looking _on-/off-line_ (in that both parts are hyphenated) outweighs the fact that neither would normally be hyphenated. Did they evolve from _on line_ through _on-line_ to _online_ the way tomorrow did?

Comment: OK, so basically the hyphen does not need to be added or even shouldn't be added since it should be clear from the context that e.g. _on/offline_ does not refer to _on or offline_ but _on or offline_. Note that theoretically switching a suffix would also be possible (I can't think of any English example right now) but again the context should make things clear.

Comment: As you say, the problem is ambiguity. *On/offline* [+/-
the hyphen] could mean: 1) Online and offline; 2) Online and then offline; 3) Online or offline; or 4) Online but then offline. Rewording is the best option.

Comment: Of possible interest: Google's n-grams for [on line/on-line/online](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+line%2Con-line%2Conline&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) and [off line/off-line/offline](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=off+line%2Coff-line%2Coffline&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) both show the two-word version was used first; the hyphenated version taking over either side of 1960 and the one-word version dominating from 1980 (online) and mid-1990s (offline).